# Let $x \in (\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty))$. Show that $x \in \{x\} \cup [\max(t,s), \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $x \in (\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty))$. Show that $x \in \{x\} \cup [\max(t,s), \infty)$.

I'm trying to figure out how $x \in (\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty))$ implies that $x \in \{x\} \cup \max(t,s)$, but I don't know how.

If $x \in (\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty))$, then $$x\in \{a\} \cup [t, \infty) \text{ and } x \in \{b\} \cup [s, \infty)$$

If $x \in [t, \infty) \cap [s, \infty)$, then $x \in [\max(t,s), \infty)$ and this is clear to me, but the singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ confuse me. What if $x=a$, then it seems that I would need to cover lots of cases if say $a \in [s, \infty)$ etc. Can I assume that $a \notin [s, \infty)$ and $b \notin [t, \infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show that $x \in \{x\} \cup [\max(t,s), \infty)$.

$x$ is always an element of $\{x\}$, and since $\{x\}\subseteq \{x\}\cup B$, it is also an element of $\{x\}\cup B$, no matter what $B$ is.